# Convertir string a System.IO.Ports.Parity C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un constructor para conectar con el puerto serie del tipo:

```
PortConx = new SerialPort(puerto);
```

Y defino sus parámetros de la siguiente manera a través de un textbox:

```
PortConx.Parity = Parity.Even;                         
PortConx.StopBits = StopBits.Two;                     
PortConx.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxDB.Text);
```

El caso es que, para parity, no puedo pasarle una variable tipo string porque el dato que me pide es del tipo `System.IO.Ports.Parity`.

¿Cómo podría convertirlo a ese tipo de dato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el método `Enum.Parse`, mediante el cual puedes convertir cualquier string en el valor del enum equivalente. Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
string parity = "Even";
PortConx.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), parity, true);
```